# Zero points of trigonometric function

Tags: limits, roots

I am supposed to find zero points of function:
$$\arctan\left ( \frac{x-1}{x} \right ) $$
Can anyone help me what is the stragety here? Am I supposed to just let y=0 and then x=0?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

$ \arctan(t)=0 \iff t=0.$ Hence

$$\arctan\left ( \frac{x-1}{x} \right )=0 \iff x-1=0 \iff x=1.$$

Comment: Thanks, but what about y axis?

Comment: The function $f(x)=\arctan\left ( \frac{x-1}{x} \right )$ is not defined for $x=0.$

Comment: Okay, thanks a lot